# Wanton stranger's

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Would you please tell what does the following mean?
Thanks in advance.

"... her skin flushed, and her body felt like a **wanton stranger's**.

Comment: What does a dictionary say???

Comment: Perhaps also add some context, where did you see this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a sentence from a Harlequin romance novel, US publisher of soft-core chick lit.

*Wanton* is defined as...

> 1. done, shown, used, etc., maliciously or unjustifiably: a wanton attack; wanton cruelty.
> 2. deliberate and without motive or provocation; uncalled-for; headstrong; willful: Why jeopardize your career in such a wanton way?
> 3. without regard for what is right, just, humane, etc.; careless; reckless: a wanton attacker of religious convictions.
> 4. sexually lawless or unrestrained; loose; lascivious; lewd: wanton behavior.
> 5. extravagantly or excessively luxurious, as a person, manner of living, or style.
> 6. luxuriant, as vegetation.

While nearly all of these definitions will work, without more context it's hard to pin down the author's precise intention. The leading contenders are the latter three (definitions 4-6) with their sexual connotations. So *wanton*, in this case, likely refers to a 'forbidden' pleasure.

*Stranger's*, on the other hand, is most likely a reference to a feeling of alienation akin to psychological dissociation of someone's mind from their body rendering them unable to make conscious, willful decisions of their own volition.

Putting all of this together a plausible interpretation of the meaning of the phrase is...

> ...her skin flushed, and her body felt a release of sexual luxuriance so unfamiliar it was as if it belonged to someone else...

Comment: Please resist doing the research the OP should have done!

Comment: @HotLicks  Will observe that admonition going forward.